# Google Drive API multipart upload gets file corrupted, size 1kb

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-drive-api

I've been trying to upload a file using the Google Drive API but I'm facing this issue and I can't seem to find the solution. When uploading an image, it uploads a corrupted file of size 1kb with correct metadata and while uploading text files, it uploads a text file with [object file] as data and not the original data of the file.

```
$("form").submit(function(evt){  
      evt.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      var control = document.getElementById("csv");
      var files = control.files;
      var dat=files[0];
   $.ajax({
       url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart',
         type: 'POST',
       contentType: false,
       data: "\n--foo_bar_baz\ \nContent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\ \n\n{ 'name': '"+dat.name+"' }\ \n--foo_bar_baz\ \nContent-Type: "+dat.type+"\ \nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\ \n\n"+dat+"\ \n--foo_bar_baz--\ ",
       headers: {
            "Authorization":"Bearer <?php echo $result["access_token"]; ?>",
            "Content-Type": "multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz",
            "Content-Length": formData.length
       },
       async: false,
       cache: false,
       enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
       processData: false,
       success: function (response) {
         var res = JSON.stringify(response);
        console.log("S: "+res);
       },
       error: function(response) {
        var res = JSON.stringify(response);
        console.log("E: "+res);
       }
   });
   return false;
 });
```

Comment: Could you post the code where you upload the file this appears to be just the metadata being uploaded not the file itself..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- You are trying to upload the file as base64. But in your script, `dat` is not base64.

  - In this case, I used `FileReader`.
- Please remove `\` of `\ \n` in `"\n--foo_bar_baz\ \nContent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\ \n\n{ 'name': '"+dat.name+"' }\ \n--foo_bar_baz\ \nContent-Type: "+dat.type+"\ \nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\ \n\n"+dat+"\ \n--foo_bar_baz--\ ",`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
$("form").submit(function(evt){  
  evt.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  var control = document.getElementById("csv");
  var files = control.files;
  var dat = files[0];

  var f = new FileReader();  // Added
  f.onload = function(){  // Added
    const base64Data = this.result.split(",")[1];  // Added
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: false,
      data: "\n--foo_bar_baz\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\n\n{'name': '"+dat.name+"'}\n--foo_bar_baz\nContent-Type: "+dat.type+"\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n"+base64Data+"\n--foo_bar_baz--\n",  // Modified
      headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer <?php echo $result["access_token"]; ?>",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz",
        "Content-Length": formData.length
      },
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      processData: false,
      success: function (response) {
        var res = JSON.stringify(response);
        console.log("S: "+res);
      },
      error: function(response) {
        var res = JSON.stringify(response);
        console.log("E: "+res);
      }
    });
  }
  f.readAsDataURL(dat);  // Added
  return false;
});
```

#### Note:

- When `uploadType=multipart` is used, the maximum file size is 5 MB. Please be careful this. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#upload_types)

If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.